# Rails: missing gem roxml

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, gem

I'm trying to setup a Rails app on an Ubuntu machine, but the app always fails with the error:

```
Missing these required gems: roxml
```

the gem **is** installed, and appears in `gem list`. The app requires a number of other gems all of which I installed without any problems, but for some reason it doesn't recognise that roxml is there.

I tried clearing out my whole ruby/rails/gem setup and starting afresh with rvm, but having gone through the process, installing all the required gems (including roxml), I'm left with the same error once again.

The full error message is:

```
Missing these required gems: roxml You're running: ruby 1.8.7.334 at /home/tim/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/bin/ruby rubygems 1.6.2 at /home/tim/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03, /home/tim/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global
```

(Note: I'm using ruby enterprise edition with rvm now, but I had the same problem pre-rvm with the normal ruby 1.8.7 and rubygems both installed from the Ubuntu repos.)

I have the same app working on another Ubuntu box with the same versions of everything, so something has gone screwy on this machine somewhere along the line, but I'm unsure where to look. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by wrapping some of the active_support loads in a conditional:

In: `/home/tim/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/roxml-3.1.6` change the first active_support parts to:

```
require 'active_support'
if Gem.loaded_specs['activesupport'].version >= Gem::Version.new('3')
    require 'active_support/inflector/inflections'
    require 'active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable'
    require 'active_support/core_ext/module/delegation'
    require 'active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options'
    require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
    require 'active_support/core_ext/string/starts_ends_with'
end
```

Comment: wow, I'd have never come up with that. Nice.

Comment: I can't take credit for the code, but it solved the problem. I think the issue is that roxml is written for Rails 3, where activesupport doesn't incldue all the extras; whereas the Rails 2 activesupport does, so it does when it tries to include non existent modules. That's my guess anyway.

Comment: I just had to set this up on another machine, so for anyone hitting this page off Google, the correct full path to the file that needs editing is: `~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@rails2/gems/roxml-3.1.6/lib/roxml.rb` where `rails2` is your gemset name and ree-1.8.7 etc. is the ruby version you're using

Answer (score 0):

I'd check two things. The first is roxml installed into RVM and not as a gem on the general system? You can check by running `/home/$user/.rvm/bin/rvm gem list`

The other gotcha is that `gem list` in RVM will list gems for all installed versions of Ruby, not just the default or active Ruby. Make sure you have actually installed roxml into the Ruby you're using.

Comment: /home/$user/.rvm/bin/gem list gives me the same gem list which includes roxml, I can also see roxml in with all the other gems at /home/tim/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/, which from the error above you'll see is definitely the ruby passenger is using